# How to open a CorelDraw WI wavelet-compressed image

Tags: windows-98, windows-95, file-format

I have a large sample of .WI images I need to convert to e.g. JPEGs, but the format now seems defunct.

The mimetype is image/wavelet.

The compression algorithm was developed by Summus, a US company that also now seems defunct.

The last CorelDraw support for the format was under 32-bit Windows (see https://community.coreldraw.com/talk/coreldraw_graphics_suite_x6/f/corel-photo-paint-x6/33558/is-wi-supported-in-x). If I go down the hardware route I need to be able to make calls to a server via e.g. REST.

I think under *nix djvulibre might be able to open the files, but I haven't been able to test this yet. Also IrfanView.

Another option is to re-implement the codec myself.

Does anyone here have any expertise in this area?

Apologies if this is not the right forum - is there a better place?

Thanks for all help!

Here's an input sample http://www.wolfgang-rolke.de/graphics/wavelet.wi

Comment: 33-bit?! :-) Do you mean NT-based or DOS-based? I think you've asked in the right place; thanks for the question.

Comment: Shouldn't be too hard to fire up a recent Linux installation in a VM and give the djvu family of tools a shot at it...

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Good point - need to check which were last CorelDraw versions to support WI

Comment: @MichaelKjörling A next step sounds like me providing a sample - how hopeful are you? :/

Comment: At least `ddjvu` can't decode it: `ddjvu: Cannot decode document.`

Comment: @jtlz2 - in your other copy of this question, you [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48366071/how-to-convert-coreldraw-wi-wavelet-compressed-image#comment99738385_48366071) that “… *My company now offers an API to do that very thing*”. Was this a genuine question, or a way to drive business to your employer?

Comment: It was at the time of course a genuine question. I wouldn't abuse SO like that. Where we are now is a true and honest statement - but the answer is unfortunately not mine to publish. Have I done something wrong or unethical in some way?

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to go down the hardware route to run 32-bit apps. 32-bit apps run on 64-bit Windows.

However, not all old apps run on newest operating systems despite the bitness. I own for example CorelDraw X3, which does not run on Windows 10. But I run it on a 32-bit Windows 7 Client OS on virtual machine regularly (on a 64-bit Windows 10 host). That setup is also useful for running 16-bit apps on a 64-bit windows Machine, which is not supported directly.